# How to get parameter name for the JMeter HTTP request?

Tags: jmeter

I'm having a scenario where I want to upload a file to the web page. I recorded the scenario using the Blazemeter plugin and when I set the parameter name in the HTTP Request I have a problem. When I inspect the uploading element(upload button) it is not consistent with the name attribute. Then how can I set the parameter name?

[image: Inspect upload button]

[image: JMeter HTTP Request]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot doesn't show the [HTML DOM Input FileUpload Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) so I'm afraid no one can help.

I would recommend just recording your file upload request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), JMeter is smart enough to detect the parameter name on its own.

Just make sure you copy your image to Jmeter's "bin" folder prior to recording as certain browsers don't report the full path of the file being uploaded therefore JMeter might fail to properly record the file upload event if the file is not present in its working directory.

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for detailed instructions on setting up JMeter for recording file upload events.

Comment: I tried the steps, but now when i record, getting an "Internal Server" error message while uploading the document.  @Dmitri T